# Mysql session data array explained

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I'm adding session data in my table using Codeigniter's session library.

**From documentation:**

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

For example in my session table i get this code:

```
a:7:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:7:"user_id";s:2:"10";s:8:"username";s:0:"";s:9:"firstname";s:3:"Dan";s:8:"lastname";s:6:"Greeb";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:18:"settings_activated";i:1;}
```

I can't find any documentation on the meaning of all the letters and numbers. What does the syntax mean?

Please notice the last session item `settings_activated`. I'm using that to check if the user entered his/her settings. It's set to 1 or 0. What does the `i` mean?

Comment: It's PHP's `serialize` output. Do not attempt to parse this by hand with anything other then `unserialize`: they are free to alter the format if it pleases them. In short, you are seeing `type:length:data` portions: a=array, s=string, i=integer. array keys are followed by their values.

Comment: @Wrikken, brilliant comment thanks! Why don't you submit it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access all session userdata simply type:

```
$data = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

With this you can access

```
echo $data['username']; // gives "johndoe"
```

If you want something specific you can do

```
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
echo $username;  // gives "johndoe"
```

As Wrikken mentioned above, the data you see in the actual table is serilized, and CI does not want you interacting with it directly - just use the Session class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to use the sessions I just wasn't sure what the syntax meant in the session array.